# Pandas groupby and make set of items

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas groupby and want to apply the function to make a set from the items in the group.

The following results in `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`:

```
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg({'size': len, 'set': set})
```

But the following works:

```
def to_set(x):
    return set(x)
    
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg({'size': len, 'set': to_set})
```

In my understanding the two expression are similar, what is the reason why the first does not work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Update

- As late as pandas version 0.22, this is an issue.
- As of pandas version 1.1.2, this is not an issue. Aggregating `set`, doesn't result in `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`.

  - Not certain when the functionality was updated.

### Original Answer

It's because `set` is of `type` `type` whereas `to_set` is of `type` `function`:

```
type(set)
<class 'type'>

def to_set(x):
    return set(x)

type(to_set)

<class 'function'>
```

According to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), `.agg()` expects:

> arg : `function` or `dict`

> Function to use for aggregating groups.

> - If a `function`, must either work when passed a `DataFrame` or when passed to
>   `DataFrame.apply`.

> - If passed a `dict`, the keys must be `DataFrame` column
>   names.

> Accepted Combinations are:

> - `string` cythonized function name
> - `function`

> - `list` of functions

> - `dict` of columns -> functions

> - nested `dict` of names -> dicts of functions

Comment: For completeness, it raises an error `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable` and it's probably because if you don't pass a *function* it expects a list of functions.

Answer (score 11):

Try using:

```
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg({'size': len, 'set': lambda x: set(x)})
```

Works for me.

Comment: If you toss a one-liner like you just did you have to include context to explain what you did and why this works. Follow the example of user Stefan will provide you more sympathy and upvotes than just the one-liner. You have to make it understandable for future readers so they can learn from it.

Comment: `'set': lambda x: set(x)` can be replaced with `'set': set`

Answer (score 5):

Update for newer versions of Pandas if you get the following error

```
SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```

```py
df = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].agg(size= len, set= lambda x: set(x))
```

Comment: `set= lambda x: set(x)` can be simplified to `set=set`

Answer (score 0):

Update for Pandas version 1.3.3 if using `.agg({'set': set})` produces the following error:

> `TypeError: Unable to infer the type of the field set`

This persists if simply using the previously suggested solution of `.agg({'set': lambda x: set(x)})`

The reason for this is that `set` does not fulfil `is_list_like` in `_aggregate` ([detailed explanation here, courtesy of @EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49539073/12155200))

A **solution** is therefore to coerce it to a list using:

> `.agg({'set': lambda x: list(set(x))})`

Comment: First, `.agg({'set': lambda x: list(set(x)}))` does not have matched parenthesis.  But if I fix to `.agg({'set': lambda x: list(set(x))})` I still get "SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported"

Comment: This should fix the problem, `.agg(lambda x: tuple(x.unique()))`